# How to convert JSON array to Java String array

Tags: java, php, android, arrays, json

I have a php file which fetches all rows from a specific column. The result is then put into an array and then json_encoded. When I Toast the output from the php file it shows a JSON string with the correct values. I need to convert this to a Java String array so I can iterate through it one by one on a button click.
I've tried multiple solutions on here but to no avail so any help will be greatly appreciated!

getImage.php

```
$sql = "SELECT advert_File_Path FROM Ads";
$result = $mysql_con->query($sql) or die('Query problem: '.mysqli_error($mysql_con));

//create array
$resultarray = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $resultarray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($resultarray);
```

MainActivity.java (only the code that is relevant)

```
 private void loadNextAdvert()
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please wait, image may take a few seconds to load...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    dbhelper = (DbHelper) new DbHelper(new DbHelper.AsyncResponse() {
        @Override
        public void processFinish(String output) {
            if(output.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || output.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                //initializes ArrayList
                stringList = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    //initializes JSONArray with output from php getImage file
                    jsonArray = new JSONArray(output);
                    if(jsonArray != null){
                        int len = jsonArray.length();
                        for(int i=0; i<len; i++){
                            stringList.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());
                        }
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(stringList), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }).execute(loadPic);
}
```

The Toast which should display the contents of the ArrayList just appears as '[]'.

Comment: What's the format of your `output` string? Or better, show the `output` string.

Comment: Hi Lym, the output looks like this [{"advert_File_Path":"toothpaste.jpg"},{"advert_File_Path":"moisturizer.jpg"},{"advert_File_Path":"shampoo.jpg"},{"advert_File_Path":"hobnobs.png"},{"advert_File_Path":"shrek.jpg"}]array<!--  -->

Comment: try `stringList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("advert_File_Path"));`

Comment: Is the last `array<!-- -->` also one part of `output` string? And, please log to see what the length of your `jsonArray` is.

Comment: I managed to remove the array<!-- -->, seems it was commented code that somehow was breaking through. I logged the length of the array but no System.out appeared

Comment: Ok I managed to get it logging the length, which is 5, and the ArrayList now logs this [{"advert_File_Path":"toothpaste.jpg"},{"advert_File_Path":"moisturizer.jpg"},{"advert_File_Path":"shampoo.jpg"},{"advert_File_Path":"hobnobs.png"},{"advert_File_Path":"shrek.jpg"}]

Comment: The only difference between the arraylist and json array are that there are now no spaces in between each record. How do I get rid of all JSON related characters and only be left with a String array like [shampoo.png, hobnobs.png, shrek.jpg]??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve it myself.
 So here goes,

Step 1. I had to remove commented code from my php file as it was breaking through somehow, thats where the  came from at the end of the JSON array.
Step 2. I had to remove an additional echo from the php file which I was using for error checking. I think I'm right in saying the only echo you want to have is the json_encode.
Step 3. Checked the length of JSONarray in Java and it was logging 5 so I now knew it was reading correctly.
Step 4. Added Pavneet_Singh's code snippet to replace `stringList.add(jsonArray.get(i).toString());`
 with `stringList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(i).optString("advert_File_Path"));`

Step 5. Converted stringList from an ArrayList to a String array using this code `stringArray = new String[stringList.size()];
stringArray = stringList.toArray(stringArray);`
Happy days! I've spent far too long trying to figure this out haha the first two steps are pretty noobish but it's sometimes the most obvious things in life that are the hardest to find. Hopefully this can help someone else too!

Answer (score 0):

use `stringList.add(jsonArray.getString(i));`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(putNesessaryValueHere);
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++){
    list.add(arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this : 

ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
for(int i = 0, count = jsonArray.length(); i< count; i++)
{
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        arrayList.add(jsonObject.toString());
    }
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```